# Plastic SCM Sync View Connection Refused

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, game-development, plasticscm

[image]

I'm trying to replicate a unity3d repo from Plastic SCM Cloud into my NAS Drive which is mapped at V:

The above error is what I get when I add my cloud repo as SRC and my local as DST so I can replicate it locally.

I have tried searching the plastic SCM forums for a solution but to no avail.

I am connected to the company intranet on a laptop that is not joined to a domain. The above error shows this is happening on local host so i'm assuming this is not related to the IT department blocking ports (they're using a PFSense firewall).

I expect to replicate my repos through the sync view for a couple of repos that we have; as it will be the start of a process of removing the repos from the cloud to our local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cloud server cannot be set as the source, it always has to be the local one.

Try to set the sync backwards: local as source and cloud as destination.

Comment: Alright so what you said fixed the sync view process.

Steps:

Create a local repository.
Go into Cloud-Sync from left menu. 
Create Sync view with the Local Repo as SRC
Add Cloud Repo as DST.

Select Pull all visible and it syncs!